# Computer-vision hardware for the blind and deaf blind

Tags: video, audio, assistive-technology

I am looking for a hardware device which will allow a blind person to simply navigate in 3D space alerting to object types and giving options for feet and hands (feet first). Use a special five-stop hardware device on the chest or voice to switch around the following, from top to bottom in the case of the switch-stop-black-plastic-vertical-bar-on-the-chest:

1. Sphere-navigate
2. Tree-navigate
3. 3D-subnavigate
4. Subobject-navigate (announce object type and navigation and subnavigation options for hands).

---

1. **Sphere-navigate**:

   - SAY “FORWARD”: allow user to spin on the legs, when possible, without getting hurt. Alert to everything in the font part of the vision sphere, or whatever is considered in front.
   - SAY “TURN LEFT”: alert to what is in an immediate area on the left of a semicircle (e.g.: door, bed, floor, table). Pick an "on the median", safe-spot on the floor. Announce the directed distance 3-distance Euclidean n-tuple saying how far each of the two hands is from the "safe spot".
   - Say: “EYE position”. This can be, upper part of the head, left hand, right hand, foot, leg, etc (elbow or whatever).
2. **Tree-navigate**:

   In the current "front area", allow the user to navigate by voice: “FRONT”, “BACK”, “PREVIOUS” (for the previous child, for the hand's field of view in front of the left hand or either eye field of view).

   This interface could also be used for a dog, pig, turtle, dolphin, whale, bird, beaver, or other animal.
3. **3D-subnavigate**:

   Ok, now we can "see" the tree. Decide whenever you want to navigate along the "safe vector". A "wave voice or sound" will use separate "components", to announce your hand increment (0,0,0) -> (N_A,N_B,N_C) (and also hand speed as the third coordinate of the tuple. I don't have a clue about how the blind person would, perceive the difference between relative displacement and speed, along this operation.

   The speaker has SAID “MOVE HAND” to perform the third operation. Just like the EYE can be anywhere, the HAND can beany where as well. Don't confuse the abstract eye and hand with the physical parts of the body announced by the machine with continuous names, with a granularity of skin location names akin to the level of detail found in advanced medical anatomy books.
4. **Subobject-navigate**:

   (announce object type and navigation and subnavigation options for hands).

   Each eye can at the same time be hand. There is a slight problem, because when one HAND moves, the other epsilon-adjacent HANDS also move.

Object appearance (eg. User turns on the tap, thus changing the tree, an alert will be given, etc.).

Also, turn on the tap and the water appears is an instantaneous appearance. An object entering the room is a continuous appearance.

If the blind person was also deaf..., place a pressure/heat/shape sensor in their mouth so they can feel everything inclusive of the voice commands (use buttons on the chest, but then they could hurt their hands in getting back to the "root-node controls, however many there could be on the chest).

To summarize, I want to know what advanced sensor-suits or computer-vision capable equipment could allow a blind or deaf blind person to navigate through space in such a way that they would be aware of their visual surroundings including object and object part positions and navigate safely through these.